# boto3.resource to create AWS S3 resource fails when proxies config is used

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

#### Python code to create AWS S3 resource with proxies config fails inside a container

session = boto3.Session(profile_name="default")

```
sts = session.client("sts")
response = sts.assume_role(
    RoleArn=assume_role_arn,
    RoleSessionName=session_name)

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
                             aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
                             aws_session_token=response['Credentials']['SessionToken'],
                             config=Config(proxies={'https': 'http://proxy.server.co.uk:8080'}))
```

This fails with error
EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://sts.amazonaws.com/"

I made sure my aws config and credentials are properly set and working because if I set proxy server details as env variable then everything works fine

#### When proxy servers config is set as environment variables everything works fine but that is not approved

```
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = 'http://proxy.server.co.uk:8080'
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = 'http://proxy.server.co.uk:8080'

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
                             aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
                             aws_session_token=response['Credentials']['SessionToken'])
```

This works fine.

#### Note: I am running these calls in a container with firewall restrictions, that's the reason I need to use proxy config